# Sky net Magento Extension

Tags: api, extensions, custom

I am using `Sky net extension` in Magento as a shipping method but getting this error.

> SkyNet Error: COULD NOT FIND THE TARIFF DETAILS FOR THE PROVIDED CRITERIA, PLEASE REDEFINE YOUR CRITERIA[image]